# Hapi js redirecting to another route with additional request data

Tags: javascript, node.js, hapi.js

In hapi.js i can redirect request from 1 route to another using

```
response.redirect('/home')
```

How do i send some data with the redirection? I tried setting it in headers

```
response.redirect('/home').header('x-token', token)
```

but this data will be lost when it reached another route.

Comment: It will be better to store the data in session

Comment: You could use cookies

Comment: What's the extra data? Could you not use params or query strings? What's the use case for the redirect?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use Yar https://github.com/hapijs/yar

```
request.yar.set('example', { key: 'value' });
response.redirect('/home')
```

In home route:

```
var example = request.yar.get('example'); // this will be "value"
```