# How can I redirect with query params

Tags: javascript, hapi.js, hapi

Issue I made: https://github.com/hapijs/hapi/issues/4307

I was wondering if anyone had come across this in hapijs before, I can't redirect with query params in the url

```js
server.route({
   path: '/test',
    method: 'GET',

    handler: async (req, h) => {
        return h.redirect('http://localhost:5000/login/callback?token=a');
    },
})
```

Comment: [take a look](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54910403/hapijs-how-to-pass-headers-while-redirecting-to-another-route) this pattern with passing token by hash is clever idea.

Comment: this is weird. but as walk around you can you session manager. [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36952649/hapi-js-redirecting-to-another-route-with-additional-request-data)

Comment: I managed to solve this, was because I had a seperate file I was importing for my login route, not sure why probably just some weirdness

will take a look at the links you gave!

Answer (score 1):

I managed to solve this, was because I had a seperate file I was importing for my login route, not sure why probably just some weirdness